Why does converting a `time_t` via `localtime()` and `mktime()` sometimes not return the same value?
I was trying to round-trip a time_t through struct tm *localtime(time_t t) and then time_t mktime(struct tm *tm).
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

bool time_t_round_trip(time_t t) {
  struct tm *tm = local_time(&t);
  if (tm == NULL) {
    return false;
  }
  time_t t2 = mktime(tm);
  return t == t2;
}

#define HOUR 3600 /* when `time_t` is a count of seconds */

int main(void) {
  time_t now;
  time(&now);
  for (time_t t = 0; t <= now; t += HOUR) {
    if (!time_t_round_trip(t)) {
      printf("%lld %s", (long long) t, ctime(&t));
    }
  puts("Done");
  return 0;
}

This works for my time zone, yet it fails for some others.  Why?
I am using GNU C17 (GCC) version 12.4.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin) compiled by GNU C version 12.4.0, GMP version 6.3.0, MPFR version 4.2.1, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.26-GMP.  Your results may vary.
const char *tzn[] = {
    "Africa/Abidjan", "Africa/Accra", "Africa/Addis_Ababa", "Africa/Algiers",
    "Africa/Asmara", "Africa/Bamako", "Africa/Bangui", "Africa/Banjul",
    "Africa/Bissau", "Africa/Blantyre", "Africa/Brazzaville",
    "Africa/Bujumbura", "Africa/Cairo", "Africa/Casablanca", "Africa/Ceuta",
    "Africa/Conakry", "Africa/Dakar", "Africa/Dar_es_Salaam", "Africa/Djibouti",
    "Africa/Douala", "Africa/El_Aaiun", "Africa/Freetown", "Africa/Gaborone",
    "Africa/Harare", "Africa/Johannesburg", "Africa/Juba", "Africa/Kampala",
    "Africa/Khartoum", "Africa/Kigali", "Africa/Kinshasa", "Africa/Lagos",
    "Africa/Libreville", "Africa/Lome", "Africa/Luanda", "Africa/Lubumbashi",
    "Africa/Lusaka", "Africa/Malabo", "Africa/Maputo", "Africa/Maseru",
    "Africa/Mbabane", "Africa/Mogadishu", "Africa/Monrovia", "Africa/Nairobi",
    "Africa/Ndjamena", "Africa/Niamey", "Africa/Nouakchott",
    "Africa/Ouagadougou", "Africa/Porto-Novo", "Africa/Sao_Tome",
    "Africa/Timbuktu", "Africa/Tripoli", "Africa/Tunis", "Africa/Windhoek",
    "America/Adak", "America/Anchorage", "America/Anguilla", "America/Antigua",
    "America/Araguaina", "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
    "America/Argentina/Catamarca", "America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia",
    "America/Argentina/Cordoba", "America/Argentina/Jujuy",
    "America/Argentina/La_Rioja", "America/Argentina/Mendoza",
    "America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos", "America/Argentina/Salta",
    "America/Argentina/San_Juan", "America/Argentina/San_Luis",
    "America/Argentina/Tucuman", "America/Argentina/Ushuaia", "America/Aruba",
    "America/Asuncion", "America/Atikokan", "America/Atka", "America/Bahia",
    "America/Bahia_Banderas", "America/Barbados", "America/Belem",
    "America/Belize", "America/Blanc-Sablon", "America/Boa_Vista",
    "America/Bogota", "America/Boise", "America/Buenos_Aires",
    "America/Cambridge_Bay", "America/Campo_Grande", "America/Cancun",
    "America/Caracas", "America/Catamarca", "America/Cayenne", "America/Cayman",
    "America/Chicago", "America/Chihuahua", "America/Coral_Harbour",
    "America/Cordoba", "America/Costa_Rica", "America/Creston",
    "America/Cuiaba", "America/Curacao", "America/Danmarkshavn",
    "America/Dawson", "America/Dawson_Creek", "America/Denver",
    "America/Detroit", "America/Dominica", "America/Edmonton",
    "America/Eirunepe", "America/El_Salvador", "America/Ensenada",
    "America/Fort_Nelson", "America/Fort_Wayne", "America/Fortaleza",
    "America/Glace_Bay", "America/Godthab", "America/Goose_Bay",
    "America/Grand_Turk", "America/Grenada", "America/Guadeloupe",
    "America/Guatemala", "America/Guayaquil", "America/Guyana",
    "America/Halifax", "America/Havana", "America/Hermosillo",
    "America/Indiana/Indianapolis", "America/Indiana/Knox",
    "America/Indiana/Marengo", "America/Indiana/Petersburg",
    "America/Indiana/Tell_City", "America/Indiana/Vevay",
    "America/Indiana/Vincennes", "America/Indiana/Winamac",
    "America/Indianapolis", "America/Inuvik", "America/Iqaluit",
    "America/Jamaica", "America/Jujuy", "America/Juneau",
    "America/Kentucky/Louisville", "America/Kentucky/Monticello",
    "America/Knox_IN", "America/Kralendijk", "America/La_Paz", "America/Lima",
    "America/Los_Angeles", "America/Louisville", "America/Lower_Princes",
    "America/Maceio", "America/Managua", "America/Manaus", "America/Marigot",
    "America/Martinique", "America/Matamoros", "America/Mazatlan",
    "America/Mendoza", "America/Menominee", "America/Merida",
    "America/Metlakatla", "America/Mexico_City", "America/Miquelon",
    "America/Moncton", "America/Monterrey", "America/Montevideo",
    "America/Montreal", "America/Montserrat", "America/Nassau",
    "America/New_York", "America/Nipigon", "America/Nome", "America/Noronha",
    "America/North_Dakota/Beulah", "America/North_Dakota/Center",
    "America/North_Dakota/New_Salem", "America/Ojinaga", "America/Panama",
    "America/Pangnirtung", "America/Paramaribo", "America/Phoenix",
    "America/Port_of_Spain", "America/Port-au-Prince", "America/Porto_Acre",
    "America/Porto_Velho", "America/Puerto_Rico", "America/Punta_Arenas",
    "America/Rainy_River", "America/Rankin_Inlet", "America/Recife",
    "America/Regina", "America/Resolute", "America/Rio_Branco",
    "America/Rosario", "America/Santa_Isabel", "America/Santarem",
    "America/Santiago", "America/Santo_Domingo", "America/Sao_Paulo",
    "America/Scoresbysund", "America/Shiprock", "America/Sitka",
    "America/St_Barthelemy", "America/St_Johns", "America/St_Kitts",
    "America/St_Lucia", "America/St_Thomas", "America/St_Vincent",
    "America/Swift_Current", "America/Tegucigalpa", "America/Thule",
    "America/Thunder_Bay", "America/Tijuana", "America/Toronto",
    "America/Tortola", "America/Vancouver", "America/Virgin",
    "America/Whitehorse", "America/Winnipeg", "America/Yakutat",
    "America/Yellowknife", "Antarctica/Casey", "Antarctica/Davis",
    "Antarctica/DumontDUrville", "Antarctica/Macquarie", "Antarctica/Mawson",
    "Antarctica/McMurdo", "Antarctica/Palmer", "Antarctica/Rothera",
    "Antarctica/South_Pole", "Antarctica/Syowa", "Antarctica/Troll",
    "Antarctica/Vostok", "Arctic/Longyearbyen", "Asia/Aden", "Asia/Almaty",
    "Asia/Amman", "Asia/Anadyr", "Asia/Aqtau", "Asia/Aqtobe", "Asia/Ashgabat",
    "Asia/Ashkhabad", "Asia/Atyrau", "Asia/Baghdad", "Asia/Bahrain",
    "Asia/Baku", "Asia/Bangkok", "Asia/Barnaul", "Asia/Beirut", "Asia/Bishkek",
    "Asia/Brunei", "Asia/Calcutta", "Asia/Chita", "Asia/Choibalsan",
    "Asia/Chongqing", "Asia/Chungking", "Asia/Colombo", "Asia/Dacca",
    "Asia/Damascus", "Asia/Dhaka", "Asia/Dili", "Asia/Dubai", "Asia/Dushanbe",
    "Asia/Famagusta", "Asia/Gaza", "Asia/Harbin", "Asia/Hebron",
    "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh", "Asia/Hong_Kong", "Asia/Hovd", "Asia/Irkutsk",
    "Asia/Istanbul", "Asia/Jakarta", "Asia/Jayapura", "Asia/Jerusalem",
    "Asia/Kabul", "Asia/Kamchatka", "Asia/Karachi", "Asia/Kashgar",
    "Asia/Kathmandu", "Asia/Katmandu", "Asia/Khandyga", "Asia/Kolkata",
    "Asia/Krasnoyarsk", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur", "Asia/Kuching", "Asia/Kuwait",
    "Asia/Macao", "Asia/Macau", "Asia/Magadan", "Asia/Makassar", "Asia/Manila",
    "Asia/Muscat", "Asia/Novokuznetsk", "Asia/Novosibirsk", "Asia/Omsk",
    "Asia/Oral", "Asia/Phnom_Penh", "Asia/Pontianak", "Asia/Pyongyang",
    "Asia/Qatar", "Asia/Qyzylorda", "Asia/Rangoon", "Asia/Riyadh",
    "Asia/Saigon", "Asia/Sakhalin", "Asia/Samarkand", "Asia/Seoul",
    "Asia/Shanghai", "Asia/Singapore", "Asia/Srednekolymsk", "Asia/Taipei",
    "Asia/Tashkent", "Asia/Tbilisi", "Asia/Tehran", "Asia/Tel_Aviv",
    "Asia/Thimbu", "Asia/Thimphu", "Asia/Tokyo", "Asia/Tomsk",
    "Asia/Ujung_Pandang", "Asia/Ulaanbaatar", "Asia/Ulan_Bator", "Asia/Urumqi",
    "Asia/Ust-Nera", "Asia/Vientiane", "Asia/Vladivostok", "Asia/Yakutsk",
    "Asia/Yangon", "Asia/Yekaterinburg", "Asia/Yerevan", "Atlantic/Azores",
    "Atlantic/Bermuda", "Atlantic/Canary", "Atlantic/Cape_Verde",
    "Atlantic/Faeroe", "Atlantic/Faroe", "Atlantic/Jan_Mayen",
    "Atlantic/Madeira", "Atlantic/Reykjavik", "Atlantic/South_Georgia",
    "Atlantic/St_Helena", "Atlantic/Stanley", "Australia/ACT",
    "Australia/Adelaide", "Australia/Brisbane", "Australia/Broken_Hill",
    "Australia/Canberra", "Australia/Currie", "Australia/Darwin",
    "Australia/Eucla", "Australia/Hobart", "Australia/LHI",
    "Australia/Lindeman", "Australia/Lord_Howe", "Australia/Melbourne",
    "Australia/North", "Australia/NSW", "Australia/Perth",
    "Australia/Queensland", "Australia/South", "Australia/Sydney",
    "Australia/Tasmania", "Australia/Victoria", "Australia/West",
    "Australia/Yancowinna", "Brazil/Acre", "Brazil/DeNoronha", "Brazil/East",
    "Brazil/West", "Canada/Atlantic", "Canada/Central", "Canada/Eastern",
    "Canada/Mountain", "Canada/Newfoundland", "Canada/Pacific",
    "Canada/Saskatchewan", "Canada/Yukon", "CET", "Chile/Continental",
    "Chile/EasterIsland", "CST6CDT", "Cuba", "EET", "Egypt", "Eire", "EST",
    "EST5EDT", "Etc/GMT", "Etc/GMT+0", "Etc/GMT+1", "Etc/GMT+10", "Etc/GMT+11",
    "Etc/GMT+12", "Etc/GMT+2", "Etc/GMT+3", "Etc/GMT+4", "Etc/GMT+5",
    "Etc/GMT+6", "Etc/GMT+7", "Etc/GMT+8", "Etc/GMT+9", "Etc/GMT0", "Etc/GMT-0",
    "Etc/GMT-1", "Etc/GMT-10", "Etc/GMT-11", "Etc/GMT-12", "Etc/GMT-13",
    "Etc/GMT-14", "Etc/GMT-2", "Etc/GMT-3", "Etc/GMT-4", "Etc/GMT-5",
    "Etc/GMT-6", "Etc/GMT-7", "Etc/GMT-8", "Etc/GMT-9", "Etc/Greenwich",
    "Etc/UCT", "Etc/Universal", "Etc/UTC", "Etc/Zulu", "Europe/Amsterdam",
    "Europe/Andorra", "Europe/Astrakhan", "Europe/Athens", "Europe/Belfast",
    "Europe/Belgrade", "Europe/Berlin", "Europe/Bratislava", "Europe/Brussels",
    "Europe/Bucharest", "Europe/Budapest", "Europe/Busingen", "Europe/Chisinau",
    "Europe/Copenhagen", "Europe/Dublin", "Europe/Gibraltar", "Europe/Guernsey",
    "Europe/Helsinki", "Europe/Isle_of_Man", "Europe/Istanbul", "Europe/Jersey",
    "Europe/Kaliningrad", "Europe/Kiev", "Europe/Kirov", "Europe/Lisbon",
    "Europe/Ljubljana", "Europe/London", "Europe/Luxembourg", "Europe/Madrid",
    "Europe/Malta", "Europe/Mariehamn", "Europe/Minsk", "Europe/Monaco",
    "Europe/Moscow", "Europe/Nicosia", "Europe/Oslo", "Europe/Paris",
    "Europe/Podgorica", "Europe/Prague", "Europe/Riga", "Europe/Rome",
    "Europe/Samara", "Europe/San_Marino", "Europe/Sarajevo", "Europe/Saratov",
    "Europe/Simferopol", "Europe/Skopje", "Europe/Sofia", "Europe/Stockholm",
    "Europe/Tallinn", "Europe/Tirane", "Europe/Tiraspol", "Europe/Ulyanovsk",
    "Europe/Uzhgorod", "Europe/Vaduz", "Europe/Vatican", "Europe/Vienna",
    "Europe/Vilnius", "Europe/Volgograd", "Europe/Warsaw", "Europe/Zagreb",
    "Europe/Zaporozhye", "Europe/Zurich", "GB", "GB-Eire", "GMT", "GMT+0",
    "GMT0", "GMT−0", "Greenwich", "Hongkong", "HST", "Iceland",
    "Indian/Antananarivo", "Indian/Chagos", "Indian/Christmas", "Indian/Cocos",
    "Indian/Comoro", "Indian/Kerguelen", "Indian/Mahe", "Indian/Maldives",
    "Indian/Mauritius", "Indian/Mayotte", "Indian/Reunion", "Iran", "Israel",
    "Jamaica", "Japan", "Kwajalein", "Libya", "MET", "Mexico/BajaNorte",
    "Mexico/BajaSur", "Mexico/General", "MST", "MST7MDT", "Navajo", "NZ",
    "NZ-CHAT", "Pacific/Apia", "Pacific/Auckland", "Pacific/Bougainville",
    "Pacific/Chatham", "Pacific/Chuuk", "Pacific/Easter", "Pacific/Efate",
    "Pacific/Enderbury", "Pacific/Fakaofo", "Pacific/Fiji", "Pacific/Funafuti",
    "Pacific/Galapagos", "Pacific/Gambier", "Pacific/Guadalcanal",
    "Pacific/Guam", "Pacific/Honolulu", "Pacific/Johnston",
    "Pacific/Kiritimati", "Pacific/Kosrae", "Pacific/Kwajalein",
    "Pacific/Majuro", "Pacific/Marquesas", "Pacific/Midway", "Pacific/Nauru",
    "Pacific/Niue", "Pacific/Norfolk", "Pacific/Noumea", "Pacific/Pago_Pago",
    "Pacific/Palau", "Pacific/Pitcairn", "Pacific/Pohnpei", "Pacific/Ponape",
    "Pacific/Port_Moresby", "Pacific/Rarotonga", "Pacific/Saipan",
    "Pacific/Samoa", "Pacific/Tahiti", "Pacific/Tarawa", "Pacific/Tongatapu",
    "Pacific/Truk", "Pacific/Wake", "Pacific/Wallis", "Pacific/Yap", "Poland",
    "Portugal", "PRC", "PST8PDT", "ROC", "ROK", "Singapore", "Turkey", "UCT",
    "Universal", "US/Alaska", "US/Aleutian", "US/Arizona", "US/Central",
    "US/Eastern", "US/East-Indiana", "US/Hawaii", "US/Indiana-Starke",
    "US/Michigan", "US/Mountain", "US/Pacific", "US/Pacific-New", "US/Samoa",
    "UTC", "WET", "W-SU", "Zulu", 0};

int set_tz(const char *tz) {
  if (tz) {
    if (setenv("TZ", tz, 1 /* overwrite */)) {
      return -1; // handle error
    }
    tzset();
    printf("### tz:'%s'\n", tz);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  for (size_t i = 0; tzn[i]; i++) {
    set_tz(tzn[i]);
    test_times();
  }
  puts("Done");
  return 0;
}

Select time zone failings.
### tz:'Africa/Algiers'
309740400 Thu Oct 25 23:00:00 1979
### tz:'Africa/Casablanca'
504918000 Tue Dec 31 23:00:00 1985
### tz:'Africa/Juba'
1612126800 Sun Jan 31 23:00:00 2021
### tz:'Africa/Khartoum'
1509483600 Tue Oct 31 23:00:00 2017
...


This is an answer-your-own-question

Standard Library mktime() lacks using struct tm members to distinguish a time zone UTC offset change.

Daylight Time
When a day has 24-hours in it, converting that day's time_t to local struct tm and then back to time_t1 presents few difficulties.
Sometimes there are more than 24 hours in a day.  When time goes from daylight time to standard time, often a hour is repeated.
localtime() differentiates the repeated hour with the .tm_isdst member of struct tm with a 0 or 1.  mktime() uses this member in re-constructing time_t.

UTC offset change
Rarely, in select time zones, a day has 25 hours due to a shift in the UTC (GMT) offset used that is not due to daylight time.  Simply that region of the earth decided to start using a different UTC offset.  struct tm has no specified member used by mktime()to differentiate that change in UTC offset.  When my mktime() is called it assumes one of the 2 offsets.  (My struct tm does have additional members, yet mktime() does not use them.)
[mktime() is specified fuzzy enough that on select machines, other struct tm members may be used - negating this problem.]
Example: Africa/Algiers 1979
void printtime(const struct tm *tm) {
  printf("%4d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d (%2d)", tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1,
      tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec, tm->tm_isdst);
}

int main(void) {
  set_tz("Africa/Algiers");
  time_t t = 309740400 - HOUR;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    struct tm *tm = gmtime(&t);
    printf("[utc %lld ", (long long) t);
    printtime(tm);
    printf("]");

    tm = localtime(&t);
    time_t t2 = mktime(tm);
    printf(" [%lld ", (long long) t2);
    printtime(tm);
    printf("]\n");
    t += HOUR;
  }
  return 0;
}

Annotated output:
### tz:'Africa/Algiers'
     time_t     utc struc tm              time_t    local time struc tm
[utc 309736800 1979/10/25 22:00:00 ( 0)] [309736800 1979/10/25 23:00:00 ( 0)]
[utc 309740400 1979/10/25 23:00:00 ( 0)] [309736800 1979/10/25 23:00:00 ( 0)] failed to round trip.
[utc 309744000 1979/10/26 00:00:00 ( 0)] [309744000 1979/10/26 00:00:00 ( 0)]


Moral of the story

localtime() + mktime(), in select local time zones and times, does not round-trip the time_t.

Be wary of using mktime() is corner cases.

Consider gmtime() + timegm() instead.  timegm() expected to be in the standard library in C2X.



There exist additional issues with 23-hour days, time zone shifts of other than 1 hour, etc.

Depending on how the tz database was built, some timezones (e.g. Europe/Dublin) may have negative DST, in which case the repeated hour(s) occur when transitioning from standard time to alternate time.

@IanAbbott Ireland simply likes to call summer time standard and winter time is the alternate: "The net effect is that time in Ireland is the same as that in Portugal and the United Kingdom."  Really more of a naming issue than a negative savings time shift.

It can also be a programming issue if the programmer only considers overlapping local  times on transitions from .is_dst=1 to .is_dst=0.

It's a shame timegm missed the boat for POSIX.1-2024!

@IanAbbott Yes there are many gotchas with time. I suspect there was 2 hour shift in daylight time at some point.  There is a current 0.5 hour one and IIRC, some place with more than 2 daylight time shifts in a year.  I recall seeing a daily GMT offset table for pre 1968 Saudi_Arabia as well as a host of DST shift date rules pre-1970 (which tz databases tend to ignore).

Yes, some places currently cancel DST during Ramadan, which can result in 4 transitions per year.

@IanAbbott Interesting.  I suspect that change can be sometimes 5 times in a 365/366 day year as Ramadan occurs per the Islamic calendar (354/355 days long).
